# Keeping getting NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object OptionsConfig.Update () (at Assets/OptionsConfig.cs:45)

Tags: unity-game-engine

I'm having a problem with my code I'm trying to turn one of my menu's on and off using the setActive method and setting the GameObject to the Object PauseMenu. I'm using an enum to set up different states for the menu but it still doesn't recognise the PauseMenu. I have checked that the name is correct and everything but I still can't figure it, so I hope one of you can help.

```
public class OptionsConfig : MonoBehaviour {
public enum MenuPhase
{
    CLOSED,
    MENU,
    INVENTORY
}

public MenuPhase currentPhase;

int CursorPosition;
private static GameObject OptionsPanelCursor;
public static GameObject PauseMenu;
public static GameObject InventoryMenu;
public static bool PauseMenuOpen;

void Start()
{
    OptionsPanelCursor = GameObject.Find("OptionsPanelCursor");
    InventoryMenu = GameObject.Find("InventoryMenu");
    PauseMenu = GameObject.Find("PausePanel");
    PauseMenuOpen = false;
    //InventoryMenu.SetActive(false);
    currentPhase = MenuPhase.CLOSED;

    Debug.Log(PauseMenuOpen);
}

// Update is called once per frame
void Update()
{
    switch (currentPhase)
    {
        case (MenuPhase.CLOSED):
            if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Escape))
            {
                {
                    Debug.Log("AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA");
                    GameObject Character = GameObject.Find("CharacterOverworld");
                    Character.GetComponent<CharacterController>().enabled = false;
                    PauseMenu.SetActive(true);
                    PauseMenuOpen = true;
                    currentPhase = MenuPhase.MENU;
                }
                if (PauseMenuOpen == true)
                {

                    GameObject Character = GameObject.Find("CharacterOverworld");
                    Character.GetComponent<CharacterController>().enabled = true;
                    PauseMenu.SetActive(false);
                    PauseMenuOpen = false;
                }
            }
            break;
        case (MenuPhase.MENU):
            if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.S))
            {
                CursorPosition = CursorPosition + 1;
                OptionsPanelCursor.transform.Translate(-31.75f, 0.0f, 0.0f);
                if (CursorPosition > 6)
                {
                    OptionsPanelCursor.transform.Translate(31.75f, 0.0f, 0.0f);
                    CursorPosition = 6;
                }
            }
            if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.W))
            {
                CursorPosition = CursorPosition - 1;
                OptionsPanelCursor.transform.Translate(31.75f, 0.0f, 0.0f);
                if (CursorPosition < 0)
                {
                    OptionsPanelCursor.transform.Translate(-31.75f, 0.0f, 0.0f);
                    CursorPosition = 0;
                }
            }
            if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Return))
            {

                if (CursorPosition == 0 || CursorPosition == -1)
                {
                    InventoryManage();
                }
                if (CursorPosition == 1)
                {

                }
                if (CursorPosition == 2)
                {

                }
                if (CursorPosition == 3)
                {

                }
                if (CursorPosition == 4)
                {

                }
                if (CursorPosition == 5)
                {

                }
                if (CursorPosition == 6 || CursorPosition == 7)
                {

                }
            }
            break;
    }
}
```

Comment: Move all your `Find` and `GetComponent` calls to `Awake` or `Start`, store the references in fields and reuse them later in your code!

Comment: is this your actual code?  I feel like we are missing an if and an else before an if... with the way this is written, `PauseMenuOpen == true` is always true.

Comment: Are you sure these objects exist at the time you are calling find? easy way to find out is to do a debug statement to see if they arent null after calling find.

Comment: Yes this all the code, PauseMenuOpen is set to false in Start() set to false and then in the menu state it's set to false and when the menu is exited it's set to false again

Comment: @HarryMcCoy I think you are misunderstanding your own code then.  There is no conditional after your `Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Escape)` therefore the line that says `PauseMenuOpen = true` is always called(as long as your are in the MenuPhase.CLOSED state), and your if soon afterwards with `PauseMenuOpen == true` is always true.

Comment: You will see this bug when you get past your null error.  Which I would be curious the results of your debug statements after calling find.

Comment: Yeah it does say that the PauseMenu is null, I also fixed the if statement problem thanks for spotting that, the problem I have is that it’s fine in the start method. But it’s not recognising it when it’s in my closed state.

Comment: Also it works the other way around if I have PauseMenu.SetActive(true) in my start function and PauseMenu.SetActive(false) in my closed state.

Comment: Actually it just started working

Answer (score 0):

Obviously the object at line 45 is null.

You use `GameObject.Find`, please check the name again, and be careful it only returns active GameObject.

1. `PauseMenu` is a public static field, so it can be set to null from other script.
2. Also because it's a public static field, after you set it inactive, then you create another `OptionsConfig` instance, the `Start` method will run again to set `PauseMenu` to null. Notice static field is shared between instances, so at this time all `OptionsConfig` will fail to run.
3. When `PauseMenu` is inactive you can still call `Start` within the script or with `GameObject.SendMessage` etc, and set `PauseMenu` to null.
4. In unity, access property of a GameObject after you destroy it, NullReferenceException will throw.

Comment: I checked the name it's exactly the same and the GameObject is active when run and set to inactive however It doesn't set it back to active again.

Comment: After read your comments under the post, I know the problem is `PauseMenu` is null. There are a lot of ways to make it null, I will update my answer to list some.